# Creative uses of Compression/Creation am Decompression/Dismantling magic

Tags: magic

Using a magic system with Mana as an external force that can be used to influence matter what would be some cool ways to use these types of magic without it sounding like complete make believe.

So my questions are:

1. Would it be possible to use them to be a proficient blacksmith?
2. Nuclear explosions and black holes are possible with infinite Mana, but with limited amounts can smaller controlled explosions(grenade like) be made for convenient use? An example would help here.
3. Would it make sense to be able to say dismantle a tooth from an animal like a wolf and then turn it into a knife by decompressing it/dismantling it to a molecular level and then reshaping it hen compressing it into a knife?

Any help would be appreciated. Would also love to hear it if you have additional ideas that dont really put the planet at risk(since the mana in one person isn't enough to allow them to compress anything enough for it to become a black hole or neutron star, but they can get fairly close).

Comment: Really this can be anything you want.  "Influencing matter" has a big scope, and no-one can tell you that what happens is wrong because it is your magic and your story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-well the process of blacksmithing is basically about heating a metal till it becomes more malleable and then adjusting it into a proper shape. But as you might see [here](https://www.artofmanliness.com/articles/blacksmithing-primer/), it is not just about heating the metal, but also about shaping it correctly. If your magic can both heat a metal to the necessary temperature and substitutes hammers by allowing you to shape that mass of heated metal at will, then yeah, there's a good chance that you can become a good magical blacksmith. However, this job is more than just hitting a metal bar till it magically gets into the shape you want. Your mages would likely still need good knowledge of blacksmithing techniques in order to adapt them for magic use.

2- magical explosions: that's a bit hard. Explosions are basically the sudden release of large amounts of energy, usually manifesting through rapid expansion of volume. For that, the easiest way in my view would be to be able to condense your magic into a volatile, highly energetic and pressurized cluster, with reactivity akin to that of nitroglycerin. If it can do so, you have some good explosives to work with. If you're not familiar with nylitroglycerin, [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=eVjdJftTtbM) might give you a good clue of what it can do.

3-you'd likely need more than one tooth. If your magic can cause a large explosion and heat up metal to 1400 degrees, it most likely can reshape matter to some extent. However, you need to watch for the mass conservation. The dismantling and reassembling isn't too bad(would need large amounts of energy to break stuff down to the molecular level and reassemble it, but not too crazy to be impossible on a magic world), but you'll need more than one tooth, unless you want a very thin knife. For an example, here's a knife made from an alligator jaw(teeth aren't bones but you get my point):[image]

Basically all of these are answered by how you want your magic to behave, the nature of your mana and to which extent magic allows users to alter the world around them.

Aditional ideas:

- using magic for enhancing materials, acting like a binding agent and making it tougher.
- using magic to influence the body, temporarily removing the natural limiters your brain and possibly aiding with the speed nervous signals travel ( myelin sheaths made of mana maybe?), granting the user temporary superhuman strength and reflexes. Note that you might want to strengthen the bones before,as your muscle power is limited for a reason. The user will also have to deal with decent pain and muscle fatigue for a few days, unless you got some fast healing magic (such use of muscle power comes at a cost) .
- mana channels used for communication, maybe through an ethereal link between mages that allows for thought and memory sharing (the ability to communicate and transfer research data fast and safely is one of the reasons we bothered inventing the internet).

Comment: For #3, assuming a mage had good control over mana and a good understanding of blacksmithing, along with enough alligator teeth, reshaping the matter to make a knife would be possible?  If yes then sharpening something like a wood, or even making a knife from wood would also be possible?

Comment: @Sevenize if they have both good control of their mana and good knowledge of blacksmith, I would say the only difference between them and a normal blacksmith would be that they substituted everything by magic (they'd also likely need to have  great concentration to use heating magic and shaping the metal properly while keeping it floating in front of them, allowing magic smiting to become a mean of proving one's magic skill ).

Comment: @Sevenize and regarding your knife, realistically we'd probably need as much concentration, if not more than your magic Smith. By real life standards making your knife would be akin to impossible, but in your world where one has enough energy to almost make a blackhole or break down a nucleus, it's doable. But remember that the mage will need vast amounts of energy to break down and remake the links that hold the molecules together, as well as great concentration to choose what links to break and where on a microscopic scale (if you can do this easily, you put the smiths to shame).

Comment: @Sevenize lastly, the wooden knife. Let me give you an upgrade: if your magic can perfectly reproduce the processes depicted [here](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/stronger-than-steel-able-to-stop-a-speeding-bullet-mdash-it-rsquo-s-super-wood/), you might even be able to make wooden knives or swords that will put those made of steel to shame. (sorry for the three comments, what you asked basically required the space of another answer to answer in a satisfactory way).

Comment: All 3 replies were helpful, and thanks for that link as well, I have a better understanding overall now

Answer (score 0):

Its best to first get an idea of how you want to develop your magic.

A good place to start is "Hard" vs. "Soft" magic dichotomy. Without getting too detailed, Hard magic obeys specific rules, where as Soft magic is more contextual to the story serving causal and emotive functions without necessarily being logical.

Once you have an idea of which style of magic you want. You can further nuance your magic depending on which type of story you want to tell.

In this way magic can be nuanced in roughly one of three ways:

1) Magic which is "Occult", in these systems magic is partially rule based, but heavily dependent on intelligent forces. That is magic is willed by divine beings and supernatural intelligence. That is to say that "Magical" phenomena are causally linked to their will. Most mythologies and religions would fall in this category. Typical tropes revolve around contacting, bargaining with, invoking and harnessing the power that supernatural beings have to offer, the more visible the divine beings and the clearer their rules the "harder" this system is. Enlightenment and seeking transcendent truths and divine consciousnesses are a common theme as well, these themes can be fussy and lend well to a "soft" magic system.

2) Magic which is just a device for breaking physics as we know it. In this way, magic can become an extension of physics on its own with clear rules for a "hard" magic system, or it can be invoked on the fly in a "soft" manner. Within this context, analogous with real physics can be created (mana, aether..etc for energy).

3) Magic is nearly purely experiential. It serves to create a backdrop to facilitate a narrative, to explore emotion and human experience. There can be rules, but these rules are usually to highlight the illogical nature of the experiential, the more soft the system the typically more absurdist the narrative.

It sounds like you want the second nuanced magic system. Now you have to decide on whether or not you want specific rules for the magic (hard), or to simply characters use magic without really giving rules (soft). All of the things you described can be performed in a "soft" magic system, so it sounds like you want a hard magic system with specific rules.

Now its a matter of setting the rules for your magic system. How much do you want your magic system to be like real-life-physics? Real-life physics is of course very complex, but some basic rules can be used to quickly determine the what can and can't happen. For instance symmetry is an important mathematical concept which characterizes aspects of physical systems. In essence, symmetry restricts how some quantities are allowed to change relative to one another. Symmetry relates to the dynamics, which is how things move in space.

Now to the point you bring up:

1) Blacksmithing in essence is heating up metal until it is malleable enough to be deformable under impulses from a hammer or similar blunt object, without cracking the crystalline structure. So the question might be, how does the magic work such that it can heat the metal and exercise impulses on said heated metal to perform blacksmithing? If the magic can produce heat, what restrictions are there, if the magic can produce impulse upon an object what are the rules for this?

2) Nuclear explosions and black holes are on vastly different energy scales and rely on different forces. Nuclear explosions are the result of strong force interactions, while black holes are the results of gravity. How might the magic affect these forces to produce these phenomena?

3) Dismantling a tooth simply requires an impulse upon the tooth, again what are the rules for producing force from magic? Shaping the tooth will require specific forces, namely shear stress. This would require precise control over force magnitude, their direction and pressure they produce.

A starting point might be how these forces are transmitted? Do they start with an incantation or with an object, or simply transmitted through will? If producing a force of specific magnitude over an area (pressure) requires lets say x amount of mana, how much mana does the typical mage have? Constructing magic in this way might allow you to quantify magic and how it interacts with physical reality. Of course, the specifics will be unique to your story and the specific scenarios your characters encounter.